# Can we install both nvidia and amd sdk's on same machine?

Tags: opencl, gpu, nvidia, amd-processor

My machine has one nvidia gpu and one AMD gpu. I would like to install both SDk's on same machine. Is it possible.? If yes, do we need to follow any steps..?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is **YES**. And you don't need any special caution to make it work.

However, as you probably know you **CAN'T** use both SDK at the same time.
So I would recomend to use only one SDK, and access both GPU using that SDK enviroment.

*We should not forget that OpenCL is not vendor dependant, and the SDK is just a library with some stubs to the OpenCL.dll. Which is what the app looks for and then uses to hooks to the GPU drivers.*

My personal recomendation, use nVIDIA SDK, since it allows fancy stuff and debug with their GPU. Then you can use the debugged app directly in the AMD device.

**EDIT: I haven't use nVIDIA for a while. Maybe is a better choise ATM to go for AMD SDK.**

Comment: Could you elaborate on the tools you talk about for the nVIDIA SDK? I find that AMD has a much better support for OpenCL than nVIDIA. It supports, for example CodeXL. Also it supports CPU execution on most modern processors. But maybe I missed something.

Comment: I should recomend one or another since I use none (I use clew with dynamic loading the OpenCL library). nVIDIA did have a good SDK, until they cut the OpenCL support to a minimum. So, taking this into account and AMD increasing their SDK support. I would say AMD is the way to go.

Comment: nvidia stopped providing opencl samples in their sdk. They only provide opencl runtime and headers/libs. opencl.dll is an icd loader. It doesn't matter how many platforms are installed. I have all 3(intel,nvidia,amd) sdks co-existing. amd has bleeding edge of opencl support